# Is the a way to project surface cuts through the entire object?

Tags: geometry

I am trying to cut this block mold at the lines I made.  The issue is that I can only cut the surface, and can't figure out how to cut all the way through, including the inner geometry.  Is there a way to project these lines through the entire object?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Knife Project` tool: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife.html#knife-project Make sure you turn on `Cut Through` option

[image]

.. Or the `Knife Tool` and hit `Z` key to make sure to turn on Cut through:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I had tried both of those already with no luck. It may be too complex of a file. Thanks anyway!